# Tag typo: compatability

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[compatability](/questions/tagged/compatability) is misspelt and should be merged with [compatibility](/questions/tagged/compatibility). I've retagged the unanswered uses but there are 50 more.

Comment: I agree, there are so many pointless tags out there, that have been replaced with newer and better tags, and the older ones are still there.

Comment: @Kevdog777 - perhaps add to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012 or do we need a new question for these extra ones

Comment: @Mark: Thank you, I have added it into that question.